# Android/SQLite - why can't I put "+" character in a database column?

Tags: android, sql

I want to store phone numbers in a column, but the code puts only numbers in column (column types is TEXT) instead of +xx... format, but the insert method gets in this format the number.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO version3 (number) VALUES("+"+"+phoneNumber+")");
```

Comment: I think you need to use an escape character. I'm not sure but + might correspond to concatenate or something in sql.

Comment: Check if column "number" is type of "String"

Comment: @Divers : sqlite does not care for column types. You need to escape stuff. But what you really need to do is not forge raw queries like that. there are tools, such as contentValues for handling that sort of stuff.

Comment: How it doesn't care if Integer it's maximum 8 bytes value? How it can store 11 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use simple quotes:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO version3 (number) VALUES("'+"+"+phoneNumber+")'");
```

(I'm not sure where you want them placed but you got the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

use `ContentValues` for that:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put( "number", "+"+phoneNumber );
db.insert( "version3", null, cv );
```